Hashicorp Vault transit auto unseal cluster is not receiving requests from transit seal configuration in main cluster (or requests are not being sent)
I am trying to set up auto-unseal for hashicorp vault using the transit secrets engine and two HA clusters. Cluster A is responsible for unsealing cluster B. My issue is that Cluster B (the main cluster) is not bieng unsealed by cluster A. I have configured everything to spec as far as I can tell from documentation and tutorials. Cluster A and B are in different namespaces, namely vault-unseal and vault respectively.
When I start the main cluster I don't see any activity at all, no logs of failed requests, no errors, the vaults just don't unseal. When I look at the /vault/audit/audit.log file I see all the activity from setting up autounseal, but there are no recorded requests from anywhere else.
To help debug, I ensured that the URL I was using is valid and reachable by making a manual wget request to the https://vault-unseal.vault-unseal.svc.cluster.local:8200/sys/audit URL (the same URL defined in the transit address field). This failed with a 403 Forbidden (as expected), and when I checked the audit logs that request was received and logged, which tells me that the pods in the main cluster are capable of making a request to the cluster responsible for unsealing.
Now what I'm trying to figure out is: Why would the main cluster not be making the request to the unseal server? Am I missing some configuration detail? It seems like the main cluster isn't recognizing or using the seal transit configuration block, do I need to enable the feature somewhere in the values.yml?
I'm having trouble debugging since I can't see any logs anywhere saying a problem of any sort occurred.
edit: One thing to note is that when I run kubectl -n vault exec vault-0 -- vault operator init the vault instance intializes using shamir seals (instead of attempting to initialize via the transit secrets engine), I'm not sure if this indicates the transit seal block is not being used or not.
here are my configuration files:
values.yml for cluster A, (auto unseal cluster)
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 156Mi
      cpu: 150m
    limits:
      memory: 156Mi
      cpu: 150m

injector:
  enabled: false

ui:
  enabled: false

server:
  # Use the Enterprise Image
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault"
    tag: "1.16.1"

  # These Resource Limits are in line with node requirements in the
  # Vault Reference Architecture for a Small Cluster
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 150Mi
      cpu: 125m
    limits:
      memory: 200Mi
      cpu: 250m

  # For HA configuration and because we need to manually init the vault,
  # we need to define custom readiness/liveness Probe settings
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true"
    initialDelaySeconds: 60

  # extraEnvironmentVars is a list of extra environment variables to set with the stateful set. These could be
  # used to include variables required for auto-unseal.
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt

  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: VAULT_TOKEN
      secretName: vault-unseal-token
      secretKey: token

  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: tls-server
    - type: secret
      name: tls-ca
    - type: secret
      name: auto-unseal

  dataStorage:
    enabled: true
    size: 400Mi

  auditStorage:
    enabled: true
    size: 500Mi

  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 2
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true

      config: |
        cluster_name = "vault-integrated-storage"
        listener "tcp" {
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
          tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
          tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-unseal-0.vault-unseal-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-unseal-1.vault-unseal-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
          autopilot {
            server_stabilization_time = "10s"
            last_contact_threshold = "10s"
            min_quorum = 1
            cleanup_dead_servers = false
            dead_server_last_contact_threshold = "10m"
            max_trailing_logs = 1000
            disable_upgrade_migration = false
          }
        }

values.yml for cluster B (main cluster)
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m
    limits:
      memory: 256Mi
      cpu: 250m

server:
  # Use the Enterprise Image
  image:
    repository: "hashicorp/vault"
    tag: "1.16.1"

  # These Resource Limits are in line with node requirements in the
  # Vault Reference Architecture for a Small Cluster
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 250Mi
      cpu: 125m
    limits:
      memory: 500Mi
      cpu: 250m

  # For HA configuration and because we need to manually init the vault,
  # we need to define custom readiness/liveness Probe settings
  readinessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
  livenessProbe:
    enabled: true
    path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true"
    initialDelaySeconds: 60

  # extraEnvironmentVars is a list of extra environment variables to set with the stateful set. These could be
  # used to include variables required for auto-unseal.
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt

  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: VAULT_TOKEN
      secretName: vault-token
      secretKey: token

  # extraVolumes is a list of extra volumes to mount. These will be exposed
  # to Vault in the path `/vault/userconfig/<name>/`.
  extraVolumes:
    - type: secret
      name: tls-server
    - type: secret
      name: tls-ca

  dataStorage:
    enabled: true
    size: 2Gi

  auditStorage:
    enabled: false
    size: 1Gi

  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: true

      config: |
        cluster_name = "vault-integrated-storage"
        listener "tcp" {
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
          tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
          tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-0.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-1.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
          retry_join {
            leader_api_addr = "https://vault-2.vault-internal:8200"
            leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
          autopilot {
            server_stabilization_time = "10s"
            last_contact_threshold = "10s"
            min_quorum = 2
            cleanup_dead_servers = true
            dead_server_last_contact_threshold = "10m"
            max_trailing_logs = 500
            disable_upgrade_migration = false
          }
          seal "transit" {
            address = "https://vault-unseal.vault-unseal.svc.cluster.local:8200"
            disable_renewal = "false"
            key_name = "autounseal"
            mount_path = "transit/"

            # disabled for now while debugging to confirm it's not a tls issue
            tls_skip_verify = "false"
            tls_server_name = "vault-unseal"
            tls_ca_cert = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
            tls_client_cert = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
            tls_client_key = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
          }
        }

To be clear, the unseal cluster (cluster A) is successfully initialized, unsealed, and has the policies etc set from each step of the official documentation, but does not receive any requests (as far as I can tell) from cluster B.

I found the issue, I accidentally pasted the seal transit {} block inside the raft configuration
